# Can this sp2 lone pair resonate?

Tags: resonance, lewis-structure

In methyl isocyanate, $\ce{CH3CNO}$, shown below,

[image]
 it seems that the nitrogen lone pair can resonate with the carbon oxygen double bond, generating a resonance structure something like acetonitrile oxide:

[image]

In that case, why is the geometry around the nitrogen in the methyl isocyanate compound bent and not linear? Can the lone pair even resonate like that?

I remember in Klein's organic chemistry, it is stated that

> Whenever an atom possesses both a π bond and a lone pair, they will not both participate in resonance

In methyl isocyanate, $\ce{CH3CNO}$, shown above, it seems that the nitrogen atom has both a π bond and a lone pair. So perhaps the sp2 lone pair on nitrogen atom cannot resonate with the carbon oxygen double bond? I am not sure.

Comment: I don't understand the title. Vinyl is CH2=CH-. It has no lone pair !

Comment: @Maurice I mean vinyl as in lone pair on a double bond (such as in N)

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever an atom possesses both a π bond and a lone pair, they will not both participate in resonance

The sentence means that only one, either the  bond or the lone pair will participate in resonance if the atom has both.

---

For example, in a pyridine, the nitrogen has a lone pair and it is also attached to a  bond.

Here, however, only the  bond participates in resonance because it is in the plane perpendicular to the molecule, while the lone pair is not.

[image]

---

Methyl isocyanate is best represented by a group of three resonance structures:

[image]

Here is the 3D structure of the most significant resonance structure of methyl isocyanate:

[image]

Comment: So C and O are both sp2 hybridized?

Comment: The first Carbon is sp3, the second sp. The oxygen atom must have either sp2 or sp hybridization, because it
needs a p orbital to participate in the C–O π bond. This oxygen atom has three
attachments (the carbon and two lone pairs), so we use sp2 hybridization.

Comment: Did this answer ur question? @DrPepper

Comment: kind of? I know in amides the N looks sp3 but it is actually sp2 because it is conjugated to the carbonyl, so I was wondering why that doesn't happen here. The N looks like it should be sp2, but if this resonance works, it would be sp because of conjugation to the C=O in H3CNCO

Comment: @DrPepper Well, look at the most significant structure, N is hybridized sp2.  When an atom that appears to be sp3 hybridized can participate in resonance, that atom is in fact sp2 hybridized. This is because resonance requires an open p-orbital to occur. Sp3 atoms have 4 sp3-hybridized orbitals but no open p-orbitals, and therefore cannot participate in resonance, while sp2-hybridized atoms can.

Comment: yes but why doesn't resonance drive the N to be sp hybridized?

Comment: If the lone pair on a nitrogen (or on any atom) participates in resonance, then that nitrogen (or whatever) atom must be 2-hybridized so that the the lone pair is in a p-like orbital to ensure appropriate symmetry for -overlap.

Comment: Yes, but in the case of H3CNCO, if the lone pair on N were to be in resonance with the carbon oxygen double bond, then you would need an additional p orbital on N, making it sp hybridized (one p orbital bonds with C and one p orbital for the lone pair in resonance). However, N is clearly not sp hybridized. Why is that?